# Java GUI with JTable

Tags: java, swing

I am displaying data in JTable through mouse event in JList. I want to know how I would change the font color of specific data after the user click in JLIst, and Here is Photo for the desired result

[image]

```
list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

            int solutionindex =list.getSelectedIndex();
            if(solutionindex==0) {

                for (int i=0;i<table.getRowCount();i++) {
                    for (int j=0;j<table.getColumnCount();j++) {

                            table.setValueAt(b.charAt(i, j), i,j);


                    }// end of second for loop

                }// end of for loop
            }               
           else {
                for (int i=0;i<table.getRowCount();i++) {
                    for (int j=0;j<table.getColumnCount();j++) {                 


        table.setValueAt(solutions.get(solutionindex1).getBoard().charAt(i, j), i,j);
                    }// end of second for loop

                }// end of for loop

            }







        table.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer(){
         @Override
         public java.awt.Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,Object value,boolean isSelected,boolean hasFocus,int row,int column) {
             java.awt.Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,value,isSelected,hasFocus,row,column);
             c.setForeground(Color.red);
             return c;
         }

     });
```

Comment: Depends on the component in the table, For buttons, setTextColor(). For JLabel, setForeground()

Comment: What have you tried up to now?

Comment: I am setting the value of JTable directly, without any other Component, just  JTale.setValue(value, numRow, numCol)

Comment: I tried to write If statement and setForeground again on the value but it did not work.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer

Comment: I have read and tried this method before it is not working @JBNizet

Comment: If you posted what you tried and explained the concrete problem you faced, we could probably help.

Comment: I have put updated the code with what I used, but it still black no change @JBNizet

Answer (score 1):

Use a `ListSelectionModel` instead of a `MouseListener` on the `JList`. (The `JList` will somewhere along the line be using the `MouseListener` to change state. Does it happen before or after you listener is fired? Depends. May change on implementation and even at runtime (which is really confusing).)

Switch the object in the table [model] from `Character` to be of a new type containing both the text and the foreground colour. In the table cell renderer, cast the cell object to the correct type, and use its colour in `setForeground`.